# Populate multiple divs through one AJAX call

Tags: html, ajax

I'm trying to make one AJAX call to another page on my site and grab the contents of two different divs.

For example: 
Another page on my site has this content

```
<div id="firstDiv">Content of first div</div>
<div id="secondDiv">Content of second div</div>
```

I want to make a single AJAX call to grab the contents of both of these divs. 
I've tried doing something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: myPageURL,
   success: function (contents) {
     if ($(contents).find('#firstDiv').length > 0) {
       var firstDivContents = $(contents).find('#firstDiv').html();
       $(firstDivContents).prependTo('#Col1');
     }
     if ($(contents).find('#secondDiv').length > 0) {
       var secondDivContents = $(contents).find('#secondDiv').html();
       $(secondDivContents).prependTo('#Col2');
     }
  }
```

});

The first IF statement runs and populates my info as expected, but the second IF statement does nothing. If I comment out the first IF statement, the second one runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happened, but when I flip the IF statements everything works fine. Ugh!